# What is the Best Mathematics editing tool?

Tags: math-software

I need a text editor for mathematics where I can easily type mathematical equations and different symbols as easily and with speed as I type plain text... I have checked some tools but they are difficult to use. Can anyone guide me please.

Comment: Perhaps learning to use TeX/LaTex would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend LaTeX / TeX , it is used by every professional. Once you get used to it, typing mathematical symbols and equations are relatively fast, and no clicking is involved. For learning and seeing how it works, i would recommend the LaTeX Equation Editor: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php